# Angular: select filter with pipe not working in diferent components

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I have 2 components, one in which I have a filter with select and another component with a table where I load data with an API. I´ve created a Pipe to filter data in the table with the select, but being in two different components it doesn´t work for me. It works for me if I have both, the select and the table, in the same component. Is there a way to make the Pipe work by having the select and the table in separate components? Thanks.

**Select html**

```
 <select class="form-control mx-sm-1 mb-2" [(ngModel)]="buscarporRegion">
        <option value="">Regiones</option>
        <option value="{{region.region}}" *ngFor="let region of paises">{{region.region}}</option>
```

**table html**

```
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let pais of paises |buscarRegion:buscarporRegion">
          <td>{{ pais.region }}</td>
          <td> {{ pais.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ pais.capital }}</td>
        </div>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**Select ts**

```
  export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

   buscarporRegion = '';
```

**table ts**

```
  export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

   buscarporRegion = '';
```

**Pipe**

```
  @Pipe({
  name: 'buscarRegion'
})
export class BuscarRegionPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    const buscarporregion = [];
    for (const recorrido of value) {
      if(recorrido.region.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1){
        buscarporregion.push(recorrido);
      }
    }
    return buscarporregion;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `buscarporRegion` from `CardComponent` to `TableComponent` by declaring `Input()` decorator in `TableComponent`.

> Table.ts

```js
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() buscarporRegion = '';

}
```

> Select.html

*Assume that the `TableComponent` selector is `app-table`.*

```
<!-- Select dropdown -->

<app-table [buscarporRegion]="buscarporRegion"></app-table>
```

While I think the `BuscarRegionPipe` filtering logic can be simplified with `.filter()`.

```js
transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    return value.filter(x => x.region.toLowerCase() == arg.toLowerCase());
}
```